# float bootstrap4 only for one size of screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, web-frameworks, web-frontend

In bootstrap 4 I want to set "float-right" for button but only for .col-sm-*
for the rest I use offset and everything is ok but for this width button is too long to offset it but I don't want to change it size.

Is this possible and if yes how I can do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 added a variety of additional tools to handle responsive needs like this:

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/#responsive

There are numerous types of `.float-*-*` utilities now to allow you to add (or remove) `float` based on Bootstrap's predefined breakpoints for `sm`, `md`, `lg`, and `xl`.

Based on your desire you would use the a combination like:

`<div class="float-sm-right float-md-none">...</div>`

This applies `float: right` for the `sm` breakpoint and removes it on `md` and wider.